# cakephp : what is the difference between $this->loadModel() and App::import('Controller','PagesController');

Tags: cakephp, model, controller

First of all, I tried to import a controller in another controller to get the view page of that controller but I failed to import. Then I try loadModel () and I get the other controllers view page. So my question is what is the difference between loadmodel and import function.

Comment: What do you mean with "get the other controllers view page"? What do you try to accomplish?

Comment: Did you already had the idea to simply read the methods doc block documentation?

Answer (score 1):

loadModel is done for loading the Model into the controller on the fly.

import is the process of loading a file and then a subsequent class inside that file.  This would be more so used for Vendors or Plugins than inside the actual controller.